# How to pass multiple words query to post request in python

Tags: python, json, post

trying to pass two words query to post request in python. Tried different patterns without success, the problem seems to be in this line, everything works great with single word query and should be working with two words:

```
query = "title:\"search this\""
```

Im getting this error:

```
{"error": {"expose": true, "statusCode": 400, "status": 400, "body": "\n{\n \"cat\": \"boats\",\n \"query\": \"title:\"search this\"\",\n \"size\": 5\n}\n", "cat": "entity.parse.failed"}}
```

Here's the code:

```
query = "title:\"search this\""

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
n = form.getvalue('n')

data = f"""
{{
"cat": "boats",
"query": "{query}",
"size": {n}
}}
"""
```

Comment: Try this: `query = 'title:\\"search this\\"'`

Comment: it works! thnks

Comment: Added an answer if you want to accept it by clicking the V and/or upvote it clicking the ^, thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer.

Query should look like this:

```
query = 'title:\\"search this\\"'
```

Then data becomes:

```
{
"cat": "boats",
"query": "title:\"search this\"",
"size": "test"
}
```